# Accessing PHP variable from static function

Tags: php

I am getting error in below code, cause am not able to access $log in static function Log which gets initialized in _construct.

```
class Logger extends Singleton{

    protected function __construct() {
        if(!class_exists("Log")) {
            include '/usr/php/Log.php';
        }
        $MONITORING_LOGFILE = "/var/log/Monitoring.log";

        ini_set('error_log', 'syslog');
        openlog($MONITORING_LOGFILE, LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL0);
        $log = Log::singleton('syslog', LOG_LOCAL0, $MONITORING_LOGFILE, array('lineFormat' => ' %{message}'), PEAR_LOG_DEBUG);
    }


    public static function Log($message){
        $log->err($message);
    }
}
```

Ok, I modified the above code

```
class Logger extends Singleton{
    private $log;

    protected function __construct() {
        if(!class_exists("Log")) {
            include '/usr/php/Log.php';
        }
        $MONITORING_LOGFILE = "/var/log/Monitoring.log";

        ini_set('error_log', 'syslog');
        openlog($MONITORING_LOGFILE, LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL0);
        $this->log = Log::singleton('syslog', LOG_LOCAL0, $MONITORING_LOGFILE, array('lineFormat' => ' %{message}'), PEAR_LOG_DEBUG);
    }


    public function Log($message){
        $this->log->err($message);
    }
}
```

and now its working fine .... just want to confirm if initializng like this is ok in Singleton pattern?

Comment: The constructor is not called if you just invoke `Logger::Log` statically. You need to retrieve the singleton instance of `Logger` from inside `Log()`. And you need to save `$log` in the constructor, or it's just a local variable that will get lost.

Comment: And what? Have you tried anything else?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access the $log variable trough a static function you need to have a reference of it:

```
class Logger extends Singleton{
    private static $log; //static instance of Log::singleton
    protected function __construct() {
        if(!class_exists("Log")) {
            include '/usr/php/Log.php';
        }
        $MONITORING_LOGFILE = "/var/log/Monitoring.log";

        ini_set('error_log', 'syslog');
        openlog($MONITORING_LOGFILE, LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL0);
        self::$log = Log::singleton('syslog', LOG_LOCAL0, $MONITORING_LOGFILE, array('lineFormat' => ' %{message}'), PEAR_LOG_DEBUG);
    }

    //static method
    public static function Log($message){
        self::$log->err($message);
    }
}
```

To create your instance of the class Logger and access the static Log function you can do the following:

```
$mylog = new Logger();
$mylog::Log("Your text here");
```

Comment: Thanks Kheshav. I cannot create an object of Logger as its extending Singleton pattern. I accessed it as Logger::getInstance()->Log("Message"); The above code works fine.